# Javascript get data from server continuously while running web application

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop

I've a little problem:
I want to get a JSON File from my running server to supply a table with latest data few times a second. 
So I planned to write an async function that is called at start and runs while my webapp is running, but after running this code, my web page doesn't answer anymore. My idea was to set a timeout, so it waits 500ms and then runs again, but obviously it doesn't work that way. What is the best thing I can do?
Thanks for help.

```
let running = false;
//called on start
function run() {
    //some code
    running = true;
    getLatestData();
    //some code
}

async function getLatestData() {
while (running) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //some code (JSON parse, set html and so on, that should work)
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/api/data", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: SetTimeout is a one time operation, use setInterval instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329387/fetch-data-from-database-and-update-webpage-continuously

Comment: Thanks. I removed the while-loop and changed the function to setInterval, now it works: ```async function setSensorData() {
    setInterval(function() {
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //some code
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/api/data", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }, 500);
}```